# Grails+Mongodb = do not persist object. Why?

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have first expirence in grails+mongodb. And I have a problem on saving object. First I connected local mongo db in such way to grails:

```
grails {
    mongo {
        host = "localhost"
        //port = 27107
        //username = "login"
        //password="pwd"
        databaseName = "db"
     }
}
```

I don't know why, but if I specify port and login+password (I create such user with such password), grails give me an error, that cann't connect to mongodb. This is a log of mongodb on daemon start:
22:47:04 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=918 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ubnt-VirtualBox

Ok, with out port and login+pass it works. Next I create domain:

```
class Cover {
    String name
    String url

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false)
        url(blank: false)
    }

    static mapping = {
        collection "cover"
        database "covers"
    }
}
```

I try to save it:

```
Cover cover = new Cover()
cover.name = title.text()
cover.url = url
println("Try to save object: ${cover.toString()}")
cover.save()
println("After save object: ${cover.toString()}")
```

What I have in output:

```
Try to save object: com.mydomain.Cover : (unsaved)
After save object: com.mydomain.Cover : 23
```

When I run shell with command 'mongo', then try to:

```
>use covers
>db.cover.find()
```

I see that there is nothing in collection. But when I look at db.cover.next_id.find() I see 23. So it seems like id increments. I can't figure out why object didn't save to mongodb. Why? Before I try to connect to mongodb and save via java driver and saving works (so mongodb seems to install correctly).

Also when I run shell I see such info >connecting to: test what means test? Where I could configure it before? May be shell connects to one db and grails to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an error, it discovers for me that source in src/groovy have to access to grails sources in specific way, so to save cover I need to create service in grails, where I cna implemet save method, and they in place where I want to call save I should get service in such way

```
def ctx = ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
CoverService coverService = ctx.coverService
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems it's saving without problems unless you've some constraint errors...
Have you tried to print the errors after saving/validating?

```
println cover.errors
```

Also you could try to recover all the instances from the application without looking in mongo with

```
println Cover.list()
```

If with this last line you can see your saved instances, maybe grails is mixing the databases as you have in databaseName=db and you later say that Cover should be saved to covers database

Comment: Ou, I lost this aspect about using in config db database. Yes it is really can be so, I will check, thanks for idea!

Comment: println Cover.list() output just [], what does it mean?

Comment: It means that it's not being saved, because the list of Covers in databse is empty. Have you tried printing the errors after saving or validating?

Comment: No, there is no errors: org.grails.datastore.mapping.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors